# Corda: Unable to run cordapp-example in IntelliJ. It runs fine using the command line method ("runnodes"). I get the following error :

Tags: corda

```
**[INFO ] 16:14:44,014 [driver-pool-thread-0] (DriverDSLImpl.kt:169) internal.DriverDSLImpl.invoke - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10013 {}
org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at** org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:787) ~[artemis-core-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:191) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:123) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:86) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:191) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:109) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:135) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:120) ~[corda-rpc-corda-3.0.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you still have a process bound to port 10013.

If the process is a Java process, try killing it using `killall java -9` on osX, or `wmic process where "name like '%java%'" delete` on Windows.